# Как добавить опцию загрузки Linux?

Tags: windows, linux

У меня не получается запустить линукс. На компьютере стоит xp и после установки линукса при пуске, в выборе системы отображается только видовс. Как это можно исправить?

**Добавлено.**

Вопрос в том, что с live cd система не пускается, а выбрасывает ошибку. При этом пробовал разные версии(lin mordiva/mint/fedora).

Выбивает

> `Busy Box v1.17.1 (ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10ubuntu1) built- in shel(ash) Enter help foralist of built-in comands. (initrams)Unable to find a medium conteining a live file sistem`

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у вас не установился загрузчик от Линукс. Если у вас используется загрузчик GRUB2, то жмите сюда: [Grub2 - восстановление](http://ubuntologia.ru/grub2-recovery).

Answer (score 1):

Вы удалили GRUB. Восстанавливал я его так:

1. ```
   max-02@max-02-desktop:~$ sudo fdisk -l

   Диск /dev/sda: 122.9 ГБ, 122942324736 байт
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14946 cylinders
   Units = цилиндры of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0x26192618

   Устр-во Загр Начало Конец Блоки Id Система
   /dev/sda1 * 1 4094 32885023+ 7 HPFS/NTFS
   /dev/sda2 4095 13241 73468577+ 5 Расширенный
   /dev/sda3 13241 14947 13706240 83 Linux
   /dev/sda5 4095 11539 59797090+ 7 HPFS/NTFS
   /dev/sda6 11539 12998 11718656 83 Linux
   /dev/sda7 12998 13241 1951744 82 Linux своп / SolarisНас
   ```

   Интересует раздел со звёздочкой. Именно на нём и есть загрузочный сектор, там стоит MBR, который заменим на GRUB:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```

   `sda1`  надо заменить на ваш раздел, если у вас несколько дисков, соответствено обозначаться будут `sdb`, `sdc` и т.д.
2. ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo chroot /mntgrub-install /dev/sda
   ```

   не прошла
3. ```
   grub-install --recheck /dev/sdaexit
   sudo umount /mnt/dev/proc:
   sudo umount /mnt/proc
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```
4. Перезагрузиться, переключиться в биосе на хард и о чудо! наконец появится GRUB.

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Обновить загрузчик ещё:

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sdasudo update-grub
   ```